# Computing the Lebesgue measure of the intersection of two one dimensional balls

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am interested in evaluating the expression, for $x, x'\in\mathbb{R}$, $k, k'>0$,
$$f(x, x', k, k')=\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{B(x, k)}(x_0)1_{B(x', k')}(x_0)\,dx_0. $$
This is of course the Lebesgue measure of $B(x, k) \cap B(x', k')$ in one dimension. The function $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^2\times[0, \infty)^2\to [0, \infty)$. I am interested in a complete characterization of $f$ in closed-form is possible.

We first consider the case $x=x'$.Then, we have that $\mu\left(B(x, k) \cap B(x', k')\right)=\min(2k, 2k')$.

Now, let us consider $x\neq x'$. Assume that $x'<x$ wlog. I know that if $k+k'\le|x-x'|$, then $f=0$. This case corresponds to an empty intersection. How do I deal with the other cases?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If $\ k+k'>x-x'>0\ $, then
$$
x_0\in B(x,k)\,\cap\,B\big(x',k'\big)\Leftrightarrow  x-k\le x_0\le x'+k'\ .
$$
What's the length of the interval $\ \big[x-k,x'+k'\big]\ $?

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of the balls is the interval $$B(x,k)\cap B(x',k')=(\max\{ x-k, x'-k'\}, \min\{x+k, x'+k'\}).$$
Here I just wrote that if we intersect two intervals, then we will get the interval where the left endpoint is given by the bigger of the two endpoints of the intervals we are intersecting and the right endpoint is given by the smaller of the two endpoints of the intervals we are intersecting.

Thus, if we want a formula for the measure, then we can write $$f(x,x', k,k')=\max\Big\{ 0,  \min\{x+k, x'+k'\}-\max\{ x-k, x'-k'\} \Big\}.$$

Here we used that the interval $(a,b)$ has length $b-a$ if $b\geq a$ and if $a>b$, then $(a,b)=\emptyset$ has length $0$.